# Flutter web firebase email_login

Tags: flutter, firebase

hey i am trying to do firebase email login only in my flutter web app, so when the user the mail of login link, I need to catch that link so that I can pass in the emaillink parameter, for android & ios there is dynamic link package, for web its not supported, any possible solution to get the link?

_firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailLink(email: email, emailLink: emailLink)